# Como fazer desaparecer os &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma `div` que vai servir de menu.

O problema é que aparecem-me este caracteres esquisitos a formatar o código e eu não os coloquei lá: `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

Esses caracteres não são visíveis pelo código, mas são visíveis através do "Inspecionar Elemento" da internet.

[image: SS]

Criei este [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d38a9dhk/) para mostrar o erro.

#### HTML/JQuery

```
<div id="menuOpt" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar-b">
        <h1>Opções</h1>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content" data-theme="b">
        <button type="button" class="ui-btn-b" ></button>
        <button type="button" class="ui-btn-b" ></button>
        <button type="button" class="ui-btn-b" ></button>
        <button type="button" class="ui-btn-b" ></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JS que fazem referencia ao menu

```
//atribuir largura ao menu das opçoes
$('#menuOpt').css({
   'width': nav_width + 'px',
// 'atributo':'Valor',
    });

    $("#menuOpt").slideToggle("slow");
```

#### Pergunta

Porque é que aparecem esses caracteres? Como é que os removo?

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir. Aqui está direitinho.

Comment: @JorgeB. aí não aparecem esses carqacteres? Eu estou a usar o google chrome. Pode ser por isso? eu estou a achas esquisito é que é a primeria vez que isto me aparece e tenho muito mais código

Comment: É o teu JavaScript que está a criar os `&nbsp;`

Comment: @JorgeB. como é que pode ser o JavaScript? Estas são as únicas referencias que faço a esse menu no **JS**       `$('#menuOpt').css({
          'width': nav_width + 'px',
//          'atributo':'Valor',
      });` e 
         
         
       `  $("#menuOpt").slideToggle("slow");`. O resto é **HTML** e **CSS**

Comment: @JorgeB. Se clicares para inspecionar elemento naquele espaçamento entre as 4 `divs` consegues ver isso no código HTML. Eu penso que isto esteja a ser implementado propositadamente pelo código `JS` para criar esses espaçamentos, pois se reparares em todos os lugares em que existem espaçamentos esse código está lá presente.

Comment: Você copiou o código do seu site/app e trouxe os `&nbsp;` consigo. Continuo a dizer que é o JS que estás a usar.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d38a9dhk/1/

Comment: @JorgeB. esse fiddle funciona bem. Mas então não percebo porque é que é o **JS** está a fazer isso? Mas se o passo para a app volta a aparecer os caracteres

Comment: Vê os JS que estás a usar, deves ter um que faz adicionar isso. Se quiseres colocar o código.

Comment: Tem como dar mais informações? que aplicação é esta, que tecnologia usa

Comment: Só tens isso de JavaScript mesmo?

Comment: @JorgeB. passei o teu codigo uma vez e não deu depois de fazer refresh. Voltei a tentar, mas desta vez esvaziei a cache e fiz um refresh pesado e já resultou e resolveu. mas se tento fazer com o meu código não da. Muito obrigado e desculpa pela confusão. Vou usar o fiddle que disponibilizaste e altera-lo para o que eu quero :P

Comment: @msm.oliveira mas resolveu o problema?

Comment: @ricardo usei o fiddle do JorgeB. na minha app e só depois de esvaziar a cache e fazer um refresh pesado é que aquilo começou a funcionar. com o  meu codigo continua a aparecer aquilo, mas vou alterar o fiddle que o JorgeB. disponibilizou para o que eu quero. Desculpa as dores de cabeça que te causei, mas muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @JorgeB. resolveu sim. só continuo a não perceber como é que aquele pedaço de **JS** causou isso

Comment: @msm.oliveira eu não sei se foi o JS pode ter sido o teu editor de HTML, pode ter sido muita coisa.

Comment: O `&nbsp;` é representação de espaço em branco. Eu não entendi qual é a necessidade de apagar isso, mas você pode simplesmente deletar o espaço vazio e quebrar a linha novamente manualmente que esses elementos irão sumir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não foi possível reproduzir. Provavelmente é algo que o JSFiddle fez e você não deve se preocupar com isto. Note que você está inspecionando um site que você não fez.

Se aparece em outra situação, era ela que você deveria ter postado.

De qualquer forma isto não é erro. Estes caracteres estão aí por algum motivo e eles são importantes. Eles representam um espaço em branco. Se você os remover terá um conteúdo diferente.

Se você não colocou na sua página e está nela (o que não parece ser o caso), elas não irão aparecer do nada. Alguma coisa está colocando e você tem que analisar o todo para descobrir o que está colocando. Ainda assim deve existir um motivo e retirar esses caracteres trará problemas. Você não colocou nada que dê para dizer porque eles estão sendo colocados. Sem mais informações, só você pode descobrir porque eles estão aí.

Comece fazer as coisas um passo de cada vez para descobrir o que está colocando isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu não postei o site, pois isto é uma aplicação e não um site. Não consigo  postar aqui a aplicação. Mas eu copiei exactamente o código que estou a usar a aplicação relativamente a este menu. Como disse num comentario na pergunta, eu não percebo porque é que poderá ser no **JS** se lá eu apenas faço referencia a esse menu para lhe atribuir uma altura e para o fazer aparecer/desaparecer

Comment: Estás errado ele copiou o HTML do código dele, se apagares os espaços entre os botões manualmente os `&nbsp;` deixam de aparecer.

Comment: Aplicação ou site, dá na mesma. O código que você postou não consta estes caracteres.

Comment: @JorgeB. exactamente: "ele copiou o HTML do código dele, se apagares os espaços entre os botões manualmente os &nbsp; deixam de aparecer"

Comment: @bigown vê isto então: http://jsfiddle.net/d38a9dhk/1/

Comment: A única coisa que eu sei é que nada é colocado sem um agente fazer isto. As informações não estão batendo. Se ele não mostrar de forma clara onde está o problema, fica difícil ajudar. Vamos ficar aqui chutando coisas. Tem que criar uma forma de reproduzir o problema de forma clara.

Answer (score 3):

Este carácter `&nbsp;` representa o carácter "espaço" (o mesmo como se você pressionar o espaço no teclado.) Ele esta a ser posto por algum de seus `javascripts`. Estes conjuntos de `&nbsp;` são inofensivos, obs. eles devem ser considerados como um único carácter.

Comment: Sao inofensivos, mas estão a alterar-me o visual da aplicação :P

Comment: Esta adicionando alguns espaços (do tananho de um carácter) isto não chega a ser _perigoso_ à aplicação.

Comment: Mas se é colocado pelo **JS** porque é que no [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/d38a9dhk/), onde não uso **JS**, também me aparecem esses caracteres?

Comment: há sim: jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1 (esta marcada esta opção) porém o browser pode estar inserido também.

Comment: @ricardo o problema é que ele copiou o HTML e colocou no FIDDLE olha vê: http://jsfiddle.net/d38a9dhk/1/

Comment: Vê o link que eu pus @ricardo

Comment: Apaguei os `&nbsp;` do código, ou seja, juntei o código todo (apaguei tudo que estava entre código) e os `&nbsp;` desapareceram.

Comment: @ricardo Não, apaguei da caixa do fiddle, juntei todo o código em uma linha e depois dei os `enter` lá.

Answer (score 1):

O @JorgeB. tem razão, você ao ter copiado esse código, trouxe também os espaços `&nbsp;` juntamente no markup.

O problema está mesmo no código HTML, se você reescrever o código linha por linha, ou simplesmente selecionar o texto HTML todo usando os atalhos do teclado - `ctrl + A` e enquanto o texto estiver selecionado apertar `shift + Tab` (para reorganizar o código e remover espaços desnecessários) e clicar `run` para correr o código novamente no jsFiddle você irá ver que estes espaços irão desaparecer.

Aqui está um exemplo no jsFiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/go35c5zy/**
Siga as intruções que estão na janela `JavaScript`